# Usage of JAXB Binder interface with XMLStreamReader StAX parser

Tags: jaxb

Is it possible to use JAXB Binder interface with StAX parser. I saw all examples saying that it needs a DOM parser to work with. The XML I am working with is too huge to fit in memory so I cant't use DOM. Is there any other alternative of modifying the XML fragment in place and marshal it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

It is not possible to use JAXB's `Binder` with StAX

**(Slightly) Longer Answer**

A JAXB `Binder` is used to sync changes between XML infoset nodes and JAXB objects.  The only XML info set nodes that are required to be supported by a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation are instances of `org.w3c.dom.Node`.  StAX doesn't really fit this model, and wouldn't work well with `Binder` methods like:

- [Object getJAXBNode(XmlNode)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html#getJAXBNode%28XmlNode%29)
- [XmlNode getXMLNode(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Binder.html#getXMLNode%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thanks Blaise for the clarification!